# JSONDecodeError in OpenStack Ubuntu 18.4

Tags: json, openstack, devstack, openstack-horizon

I am a beginner of OpenStack devstack. When I install OpenStack and login in to the system I notice that there was no any error messages there. But after rebooting my machine and login in to the instance and overview sections, i found that there was a error, which is called

> JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

. Still I don't have a idea how to solve this. Please hep me to achive this. Appreciate you help.

```
JSONDecodeError at /project/instances/

Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://10.1.1.140/dashboard/project/instances/
Django Version:     2.2.12
Exception Type:     JSONDecodeError
Exception Value:    

Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Exception Location:     /usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py in raw_decode, line 357
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python3
Python Version:     3.6.9
Python Path:    

['/opt/stack/horizon',
 '/opt/stack/horizon',
 '/opt/stack/keystone',
 '/opt/stack/glance',
 '/opt/stack/cinder',
 '/opt/stack/neutron',
 '/opt/stack/nova',
 '/opt/stack/placement',
 '/opt/stack/horizon',
 '/opt/stack/tempest',
 '/usr/lib/python36.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.6',
 '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages',
 '/opt/stack/horizon/openstack_dashboard']

Server time:    Sat, 4 Apr 2020 14:09:49 +0000
```

***Traceback***

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://10.1.1.140/dashboard/project/instances/

Django Version: 2.2.12
Python Version: 3.6.9
Installed Applications:
['openstack_dashboard.dashboards.project',
 'openstack_dashboard.dashboards.admin',
 'openstack_dashboard.dashboards.identity',
 'openstack_dashboard.dashboards.settings',
 'openstack_dashboard',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.humanize',
 'django_pyscss',
 'debreach',
 'openstack_dashboard.django_pyscss_fix',
 'compressor',
 'horizon',
 'openstack_auth']
Installed Middleware:
('openstack_auth.middleware.OpenstackAuthMonkeyPatchMiddleware',
 'debreach.middleware.RandomCommentMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'horizon.middleware.OperationLogMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'horizon.middleware.HorizonMiddleware',
 'horizon.themes.ThemeMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'openstack_dashboard.contrib.developer.profiler.middleware.ProfilerClientMiddleware',
 'openstack_dashboard.contrib.developer.profiler.middleware.ProfilerMiddleware')



Traceback:

File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py" in raw_decode
  355.             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)

During handling of the above exception (0), another exception occurred:

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/opt/stack/horizon/horizon/decorators.py" in dec
  52.             return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/opt/stack/horizon/horizon/decorators.py" in dec
  36.         return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/opt/stack/horizon/horizon/decorators.py" in dec
  36.         return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/opt/stack/horizon/horizon/decorators.py" in dec
  113.         return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/opt/stack/horizon/horizon/decorators.py" in dec
  84.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  71.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  97.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/opt/stack/horizon/horizon/tables/views.py" in get
  223.         handled = self.construct_tables()

File "/opt/stack/horizon/horizon/tables/views.py" in construct_tables
  214.             handled = self.handle_table(table)

File "/opt/stack/horizon/horizon/tables/views.py" in handle_table
  123.         data = self._get_data_dict()

File "/opt/stack/horizon/horizon/tables/views.py" in _get_data_dict
  252.             self._data = {self.table_class._meta.name: self.get_data()}

File "/opt/stack/horizon/openstack_dashboard/dashboards/project/instances/views.py" in get_data
  156.                 self._get_images, self._get_flavors, self._get_volumes

File "/opt/stack/horizon/openstack_dashboard/utils/futurist_utils.py" in call_functions_parallel
  50.     return tuple(f.result() for f in futures)

File "/opt/stack/horizon/openstack_dashboard/utils/futurist_utils.py" in <genexpr>
  50.     return tuple(f.result() for f in futures)

File "/usr/lib/python3.6/concurrent/futures/_base.py" in result
  425.                 return self.__get_result()

File "/usr/lib/python3.6/concurrent/futures/_base.py" in __get_result
  384.             raise self._exception

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/futurist/_utils.py" in run
  52.             result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)

File "/opt/stack/horizon/openstack_dashboard/dashboards/project/instances/views.py" in _get_volumes
  147.             exceptions.handle(self.request, ignore=True)

File "/opt/stack/horizon/openstack_dashboard/dashboards/project/instances/views.py" in _get_volumes
  144.             volumes = api.cinder.volume_list(self.request)

File "/opt/stack/horizon/openstack_dashboard/api/cinder.py" in volume_list
  296.         sort_dir=sort_dir)

File "/opt/stack/horizon/openstack_dashboard/api/cinder.py" in volume_list_paged
  333.     c_client = _cinderclient_with_generic_groups(request)

File "/opt/stack/horizon/openstack_dashboard/api/cinder.py" in _cinderclient_with_generic_groups
  285.     return _cinderclient_with_features(request, 'groups')

File "/opt/stack/horizon/openstack_dashboard/api/cinder.py" in _cinderclient_with_features
  267.     version = get_microversion(request, features)

File "/opt/stack/horizon/openstack_dashboard/api/cinder.py" in get_microversion
  260.                                                         insecure, cacert)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/cinderclient/client.py" in get_server_version
  117.         data = json.loads(response.text)

File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py" in loads
  354.         return _default_decoder.decode(s)

File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py" in decode
  339.         obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())

File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py" in raw_decode
  357.             raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None

Exception Type: JSONDecodeError at /project/instances/
Exception Value: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this problem by restarting my database, and then by restarting the Cinder service.
On my devstack setup, that consisted of running
`sudo service mysql restart` and `sudo service devstack@c-api restart`

The problem was that Cinder was not responding to the request that the horizon dashboard. As can be seen in your stack trace here

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/cinderclient/client.py" in get_server_version
  117.         data = json.loads(response.text)
```

A further diagnosis, is that by running the command `openstack volume list` (which calls the cinder api) returns `Internal Server Error (HTTP 500)`

Answer (score 1):

This solved for me horizon query problem under ubuntu 18.04 :

```sh
sudo systemctl restart devstack@*
```

Restart all devstack services.